# R calculating proportion over two-way-table with two categorical variables and add new variable

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I cannot find an answer to my following problem: How do I easily calculate the proportion over a two-way-table of two categorical variables and add that value as a new variable? I would like to use dplyr and mutate.

```
Gender <- c("Female","Female","Male","Male") 
Believer <- c("Yes","No","Yes","No")
Count <- c(100,50,200,150)
dat <- data.frame(Gender,Believer,Count)

dat
Gender Believer Count
1 Female      Yes   100
2 Female       No    50
3   Male      Yes   200
4   Male       No   150

str(dat)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Gender  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 1 2 2
 $ Believer: Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 1 2 1
 $ Count   : num  100 50 200 150
```

I would like to have a result as follows:

```
dat
Gender Believer Count   Prop
1 Female      Yes   100  0.02
2 Female       No    50  0.01
3   Male      Yes   200  0.04
4   Male       No   150  0.03
```

I would very much appreciate an answer. I for sure is very simple but I do not find it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` as OP suggests

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(Prop = Count / sum(Count))

  Gender Believer Count Prop
1 Female      Yes   100  0.2
2 Female       No    50  0.1
3   Male      Yes   200  0.4
4   Male       No   150  0.3
```

(even though I don't know how you got 0.02 for example, just `(sum(Count) * 10)` in this case) :

```
dat %>% mutate(Prop = Count / (sum(Count) * 10))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it was easy but somehow did not find the clue. The 0.02's are typos. Sorry about that.